# CSS specification of column-count in Webkit-based browsers

Tags: css, webkit

I have used [this tutorial](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/) to implement a masonry layout in my current project.

When testing it on some Webkit-based browsers (up-to-date Google Chrome and Vivaldi) though, there's a problem in that the browser does not honor the `column-count` specification.

[Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/plunk/GfjrN7YK5DkJB9JGOZMO)

In the specific case of desktop devices (`md` or `lg`), when the container contains two elements, those children are stacked vertically instead of occupying two columns. With Firefox, the content uses two columns and the rightmost column is empty.

When there are three elements in the container, Firefox uses three columns whereas Webkit uses only two columns. It takes at least 4 or 5 elements to have Webkit actually use three columns, which means that there is ample space. To test the cut point, move the opening comment line `<!--` up and down the HTML source code.

Is there anything I can do to have the "correct" behavior like in Firefox and IE? The way I understand columns is that content is distributed over the specified number of columns when there's enough space that the content can fit in. I am wrong? Or is it just Webkit throwing a whim at me?

Answer (score 0):

```
.example {
  -webkit-column-count: value;
     -moz-column-count: value;
          column-count: value;
 }
```

Try using [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) and [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count).

Comment: I'm using both prefixed and not-prefixed versions in the plunkr I referenced in the question. I haven't been able to figure out what you do differently.

Comment: I was sure it's gonna work with ` -webkit-perspective:1` , that's why I referred to caniuse, but my answer is wrong. Trying to figure it out now, interesting case.

Comment: btw, thanks for the Caniuse reference. It'll be immensely helpful.

Comment: My pleasure. Thing is I have no idea why it doesn't work as expected in chrome. Maybe it has something to do with latest updates?